# DATETIME in Javascript in Database

Tags: javascript, database, datetime

I'm trying to store a `DATETIME` in my Database using Javascript, there is just one problem, it doesn't store the `DATETIME` which was set to `DATETIME` in the database.

This is how I store and get the `DATETIME`,

```
var currentTime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
query('UPDATE `users` SET `claimed`='+currentTime+' WHERE`id`='+pool.escape(user.steamid));
```

The problem is that the database doesn't update, but it can't be the fault of the database, did I miss something? Can you not store a Javascript "String" as Datetime?

Thanks.

Comment: You can save as "string". But in your case, it's not a string. Try 'UPDATE `users` SET `claimed`="'+currentTime+'"  WHERE ..... .. enclose with string " " to make it string.

Comment: @VinodKumar yep, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript varible is ok.

Try this

```
query('UPDATE `users` SET `claimed`="'+currentTime+'" WHERE`id`='+pool.escape(user.steamid));
```

Comment: Yeah! That did it! Thanks a lot bro.